# Why does Ubuntu keep saying unattended-upgrades could not be installed?

Tags: 18.04, unattended-upgrades

Since a couple of days, when I log in Ubuntu 18.04, I receive the following message:

```
13 updates could not be installed automatically. For more details,
see /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
```

I do not see anything particular in the log file.  The following lines are repeated every day (sometimes with an update):

```
2019-12-17 05:03:16,572 INFO Paquets faisant initialement partie de la liste noireÂ : 
2019-12-17 05:03:16,580 INFO Paquets initialement sur la liste blanche: 
2019-12-17 05:03:16,580 INFO DÃ©marrage du script de mise Ã  niveau automatique
2019-12-17 05:03:16,580 INFO Les origines autorisÃ©es sontÂ : o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
2019-12-17 06:40:06,184 INFO Paquets faisant initialement partie de la liste noireÂ : 
2019-12-17 06:40:06,201 INFO Paquets initialement sur la liste blanche: 
2019-12-17 06:40:06,201 INFO DÃ©marrage du script de mise Ã  niveau automatique
2019-12-17 06:40:06,201 INFO Les origines autorisÃ©es sontÂ : o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
2019-12-17 06:40:12,125 INFO Aucun paquet Ã  mettre Ã  niveau automatiquement ni Ã  supprimer automatiquement
```

If I manually force an update, the system says everything is up to date:

```
sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is this above-mentioned message important? What can I do to eliminate it?

Comment: @OrganicMarble: yes, partially: if I remove the file 'kept-back', the message disappears.  But I do not know why that list suddenly contains 13 packages. Anyway, congratulations for finding it out!

Comment: You can use the command `apt-mark showhold` to get a list of packages that are held back from updating on your system. In my system, this list was identical to what was shown at login.  I believe there was a recent update (12/4/2019) of `unattended-upgrades` that caused this message to be displayed at login. I never saw it before that date.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I had tried that command and just retried.  Same result: empty list, contrary to the content of `kept-back`.  I wonder what will happen with the next execution of `unatended-upgrades`.

Comment: That's odd! Perhaps tomorrow the login message won't be there.

Comment: Unattended-upgrades default settings are only to upgrade packages in the -security pocket of the Ubuntu repos. Unless you have changed the settings, packages in -updates, -backports, PPAs, third-party repos, etc., will be in `kept-back`

Comment: After execution of `unattended-upgrades`this morning, the message is not there and there is no `kept-back`anymore.